# Expected object or value: Importing JSON into Python (Pandas)

Tags: json, pandas, parsing, machine-learning, serialization

I am using Python 3 and I tried with

```
data = pd.read_json('file.json',encoding="utf-8",orient='records',lines=True)
```

But It gives me:

***ValueError: Expected object or value***

This is the structure of the Json file, just a quick sample

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5af1b1fd4f4733eacf11dba9"), 
"centralPath" : "XXX2", 
"viewStats" : [
    {
        "totalViews" : NumberInt(3642), 
        "totalSheets" : NumberInt(393), 
        "totalSchedules" : NumberInt(427), 
        "viewsOnSheet" : NumberInt(1949), 
        "viewsOnSheetWithTemplate" : NumberInt(625), 
        "schedulesOnSheet" : NumberInt(371), 
        "unclippedViews" : NumberInt(876), 
        "createdOn" : ISODate("2017-10-13T18:06:45.291+0000"), 
        "_id" : ObjectId("59e100b535eeefcc27ee0802")
    }, 
    {
        "totalViews" : NumberInt(3642), 
        "totalSheets" : NumberInt(393), 
        "totalSchedules" : NumberInt(427), 
        "viewsOnSheet" : NumberInt(1949), 
        "viewsOnSheetWithTemplate" : NumberInt(625), 
        "schedulesOnSheet" : NumberInt(371), 
        "unclippedViews" : NumberInt(876), 
        "createdOn" : ISODate("2017-10-13T19:11:47.530+0000"), 
        "_id" : ObjectId("59e10ff3eb0de5740c248df2")
    }
]
```

}

With this method, I am able to see the data but I would like to have

```
with open('file.json', 'r') as viewsmc:
    data = viewsmc.readlines()
```

With this the output

```
['{ \n',
 '    "_id" : ObjectId("5af1b1fd4f4733eacf11dba9"), \n',
 '    "centralPath" : "XXX2", \n',
 '    "viewStats" : [\n',
 '        {\n',
 '            "totalViews" : NumberInt(3642), \n',
 '            "totalSheets" : NumberInt(393), \n',
 '            "totalSchedules" : NumberInt(427), \n',
 '            "viewsOnSheet" : NumberInt(1949), \n',
 '            "viewsOnSheetWithTemplate" : NumberInt(625), \n',
 '            "schedulesOnSheet" : NumberInt(371), \n',
 '            "unclippedViews" : NumberInt(876), \n',
 '            "createdOn" : ISODate("2017-10-13T18:06:45.291+0000"), \n',
 '            "_id" : ObjectId("59e100b535eeefcc27ee0802")\n',
 '        }, \n',
```

I tried all different method and solution reported on the read_json / https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html
and load/ loads(str) etc. but nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Issue was with the format of the JSON file, 
we tested with https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and modify with a regular expression If you have better suggestions let me know.

import re

```
with open("views3.json", "r+") as read_file:
   data = read_file.read()
   x = re.sub("\w+\((.+)\)", r'\1', data)
   print(x)
```

read_file.closed

Answer (score 0):

do you want that?: use modul json for reading file.json

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('file.json') as viewsmc:
   data = json.load(viewsmc)
print data #you have a dict

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Frenchy, I appreciate your help, Yes I import those libraries and I have also tried this out and it wasn't working. (Error Message was: Expecting value: line 2 column 13 (char 15))


'

Comment: So another things: in fact your export is not good (i suppose from mongodb), if you put off ObjectId,NumberInt and so on all is okay...IF your mongo collection does not include NumberInt, and mongoexport creates a json document that includes NumberInt, this is a bug. you could validate your json [here](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

Comment: Thanks again Franchy, how can I make my .json file editable for regular expressions?